# Xcode and tag searching

Tags: ios, objective-c

A simple inquiry.

When using Objective-C / Swift and one decides to implement tags for objects within the storyboard, how does the system search for the tags?

Does it approach this as a linear search? Therefore, implying that tags with a lower number value will be faster to search for? Or does it approach this entirely differently?

For example:

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:1];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Elderberries"];
```

vs

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:100000000];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Motherless_Goat"];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experiment, below is the code

```
//adding 30000 tag at first position
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 30000];
label.tag = 30000;
[self.view addSubview:label];

for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    label.tag = i;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}

NSTimeInterval currentTime, fetchTime;
currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
UILabel *label1 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:5];
fetchTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"Label:%@ = %f",label1.text, fetchTime - currentTime);



currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
UILabel *label2 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
fetchTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"Label:%@ = %f",label2.text, fetchTime - currentTime);


currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
UILabel *label3 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1000];
fetchTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"Label:%@ = %f",label3.text, fetchTime - currentTime);

currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
UILabel *label4 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:5000];
fetchTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"Label:%@ = %f",label4.text, fetchTime - currentTime);


currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
UILabel *label5 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:10000];
fetchTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"Label:%@ = %f",label5.text, fetchTime - currentTime);


currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
UILabel *label6 = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:30000];
fetchTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSLog(@"Label:%@ = %f",label6.text, fetchTime - currentTime);
```

And below were the logs (reformatted so that comparison is easy)

```
Label:5 =     0.000011
Label:100 =   0.000043
Label:1000 =  0.000346
Label:5000 =  0.001169
Label:10000 = 0.002115
Label:30000 = 0.000009
```

#### Conclusion:

The `viewWithTag:` will take more time for higher tags (only if there are large number of objects), it might be possible that search is linear which I think is the case because `view.subViews` gives you the array in the order they are added not by the tag. Yes it takes more time and it almost work as linear search.

The time depends upon the index at which subview was added, in the above case time for `30000` tag is minimum than all other tags because it was added at first index.

The posible implementation of `viewWithTag:` could be like this

```
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag {
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if (view.tag == tag) {
            return view;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: If you reverse the creation of the labels so that it creates tag 30,000 first and tag 0 last then the times get reversed.

Label:1 = 0.005771
Label:100 = 0.005912
Label:1000 = 0.005716
Label:5000 = 0.004726
Label:10000 = 0.003773
Label:30000 = 0.000003

So it looks like the search is a linear search of the `subViews` array rather than a linear search of the tag value space.